# Generate links in multi-language website

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, middleware, multilingual

I have multi-language website. In order to locale website I use middleware which look like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    App::setlocale('pl');
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('lang', 'pl'), true, 1440);
    return $next($request);
}
```

My names of roote looks like this: 'pl.articles' or 'en.acritcles' so I use cookie to generate links into view. For example:

```
@if(Cookie::get('lang') == 'pl')
    <li><a href="{{ route('pl.allwomens') }}">@lang('category.womens')</a></li>
@else
  <li><a href="{{ route('en.allwomens') }}">@lang('category.womens')</a></li>
@endif
```

It works but I have a little problem. Actully when I change a language, links will bo to a previous version. So I must reload website in order to change links to. Sometimes I click some link and langage of my website will chang. I click again and language will come back to previous version. Where is the problem?
I use middleware in a group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pl', 'middleware' => ['PLLanguage', 'globalStats']], function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Middleware called "Language"

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure, Session, Auth;

class SetLanguage {


    protected $languages = ['en','pl'];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(isset($request->applocale)){

            if(in_array($request->applocale, $this->languages)){
                if(!Session::has('locale'))
                { 
                    Session::put('locale', $request->applocale);

                } else if( Session::get('locale') != $request->applocale ){
                    Session::put('locale', $request->applocale);
                    app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
                }
            }

            else abort(500, 'Bad request, requested language not found');

        }

        app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale'));

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

put this middleware in your Web group in Kernel.php file

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetLanguage::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

create language change form

```
<a href="#" onclick="setLanguage(event, 'en')">English</a>
<a href="#" onclick="setLanguage(event, 'pl')">ქართული</a>
<form action="/setlanguage" method="POST" style="display: none" id="languageForm">
    @csrf
    <input id="applocale" type="text" name="applocale" >
</form>
<script>
    function setLanguage(e, lang){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#applocale').val(lang);
        $('#languageForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

so language will be set on every form submit

then in your views you can use

```
@php $lang = app()->getLocale(); @endphp
<li><a href="{{ route($lang.'.allwomens') }}">@lang('category.womens')</a></li>
```

Comment: Could you show my code? I would must change a lot of think in my code and I prefer cookie than session becouse I want to remember choice of user.